# Which region endpoint should AWS Java SDK v2 be using for Route 53?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

On Windows 10 I'm using the AWS Java SDK v2 (`software.amazon.awssdk:route53:2.8.3`) and I'm trying to merely connect and list all my Route 53 hosted zones. I have `us-west-1` specified in my user configuration (in my `.aws/config` file) as the default region.

I create a `Route53Client` using the following:

```java
Route53Client route53Client = Route53Client.builder().build();
```

Note that I don't indicate a region, because in the [online documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) it says:

> When you submit requests using the AWS CLI or SDKs, either leave the Region and endpoint unspecified, or specify us-east-1 as the Region.

I then try to list hosted zones using something like this:

```java
Set<HostedZone> hostedZones = client.listHostedZonesPaginator().stream()
  .flatMap(response -> response.hostedZones().stream())
  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

In the logs I see a debug message like this:

> `[DEBUG] Unable to load region from software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.SystemSettingsRegionProvider@...:Unable to load region from system settings. Region must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_REGION) or  system property (aws.region).`

Then it throws a `java.net.UnknownHostException` for `route53.us-west-1.amazonaws.com`.

Granted I am on a spotty Internet connection right now. Is that the correct endpoint? If it is, the why isn't that endpoint listed at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html ? If it isn't, why is it trying to connect to a `us-west1` endpoint, if I'm following the online documentation (as I quoted above), which indicates that a region need not be indicated? Or is the problem simply my Internet connection and spotty DNS lookup at the moment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The AWS SDK development team decided to require Route53 requests to explicitly indicate the `Region.AWS_GLOBAL` or requests would not work, as someone [noted](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/456#issuecomment-380160253) in [Issue #456](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/456) for the SDK:

> To access Route53 you would currently need to specify the AWS_GLOBAL region. This was done to prevent customers from using global services and not realizing that for this service your calls are likely not staying in region and could potentially be spanning the globe.

Unfortunately Amazon didn't bother documenting this in the SDK (that I could find), and didn't provide a helpful error message, instead assuming developers would somehow guess the problem when the SDK tried to access an endpoint that did not exist even though the SDK was being used according to the API and according to the online documentation.

In short the Route53 client must be created like this:

```java
route53Client = Route53Client.builder().region(Region.AWS_GLOBAL).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the AWS Route 53 V2 Code example that lists hosted zones:

```
package com.example.route;

//snippet-start:[route.java2.list_zones.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.route53.Route53Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.route53.model.HostedZone;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.route53.model.Route53Exception;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.route53.model.ListHostedZonesResponse;
import java.util.List;
//snippet-end:[route.java2.list_zones.import]

public class ListHostedZones {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Region region = Region.AWS_GLOBAL;
        Route53Client route53Client = Route53Client.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        listZones(route53Client);
    }

    //snippet-start:[route.java2.list_zones.main]
    public static void listZones(Route53Client route53Client) {

        try {

            ListHostedZonesResponse zonesResponse = route53Client.listHostedZones();
            List<HostedZone> checklist = zonesResponse.hostedZones();

            for (HostedZone check: checklist) {
                System.out.println("The name is : "+check.name());
            }

        } catch (Route53Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    //snippet-end:[route.java2.list_zones.main]
}
```